# Concept of C++ pointers in Actionscript-Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, actionscript-3

Learning the basicsof C++ and trying to wrap my head around pointers and when you would use them. Coming from a Javascript-Actionscript background I can't think of anything similar.

Can anyone suggest any equivalents to pointers in Javascript or Actionscript 3 and also, when you might use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick and easy answer is that there's nothing similar to pointers in javascript or actionscript, but I might be able to draw some tenuous similes for you.

All languages implement the functionality given to you by pointers, but most modern ones hide them from the programmer.  C/C++ gives you a lot of power by exposing them and requiring you to use them; most other languages keep programmers from hurting themselves by hiding them.  Being responsible for your own memory management can be dangerous.  Also, remember that C and C++ are earlier languages than JavaScript, ActionScript, or even Java or C# - pointer syntax was necessary for those "primitive" times.  (C is very close to assembly code in its memory management, and C++ comes directly from C.)

But every programming language still has to manage memory - they have to let you create (new) variables, access those variables, and store references to them.  The same is true for functions.

Look at some of the things you do, and think of them with a pointer mindset.

- When you set a variable equal to a named function, your virtual machine is finding the function in memory, and setting the variable to point to that memory.  (In C, this is called a function pointer.  C++ uses this as well.)
- When you set a variable equal to an anonymous function, your virtual machine creates the function somewhere in memory, sets the variable to point to that area in its memory and lets you refer to it.
- When you call new, you're creating a new reference.  Again, the virtual machine is creating a spot in memory, and giving you a way to access it.
- When you pass an object into a function, you're not passing the whole object, you're passing a reference to it.  The VM uses your variable to tell the function what part of memory to play with and how it should behave.

If you start doing a lot of programming in C/C++, you'll find you use pointers (and references, which are a related concept) in almost everything you do.  Once you get used to it, you'll find that you've been using similar concepts all along - you just didn't have to be as explicitly aware of what you were doing.  You'll be a lot more aware of what every programming language has to do with its memory - whether implicitly or explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

By considering a pointer (or reference), a value that [hold the address of the actual object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29);

In AS3 any reference to a sub-class of 'Object' is a pointer:

```
var a:Point = new Point(0, 0);
var pointer:Point;
pointer = a;
```

Any modification to the object 'pointer' actually modifies 'a' and so 'pointer' is a pointer/reference (holds the address) to 'a', even when passed to functions as arguments: the parameter is a pointer (passed by reference and not by value).

Primitives types however, which aren't sub-classes of 'Object' as is 'Point', are always passed by value (copied) to a new variable or parameter; Primitive types include int, uint, Boolean, Number, String.

By the way, [C++ pointers are a special kind of 'reference' implementation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a similar concept in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or [actionscript-3](/questions/tagged/actionscript-3).

C++ overtook the pointer concept from C language. Basically C/C++ pointers hold concrete memory addresses that *point* to type instances, but C++ added polymorphic resolution for class types.

The preferred mechanism to pass (as function parameters) or store (as variables, class attributes) references to type instances in C++ is (uummm) references or values. This might not be possible or wanted in all situations.

C++ references (see `&` type specifier) are basically the same, but **must** be initialized to a valid memory address referencing a valid type instance. Pointers in contrast can also hold a `NULL` value, indicating there's no valid type instance referenced.

Further it's discouraged to use raw pointer types (C like) in C++ at all. The standard library offers several pointer like surrogates (smart pointer types) for particular semantic use case situations of instance references, addressing lifetime management a.s.o. (recall C++ has no intrinsic garbage collection mechanism).

There are lot of further resources about this topic on Google and SO.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good 1-to-1 mapping. Pointer are hidden in other languages because, while very powerful, are also prone to crashing applications.

Generally, you use pointers when the lifetime of the object you are working with allows it to escape your creation context. Even then, it is best-practice to wrap a pointer in another object that will automatically delete the pointer when appropriate.

If you put some study into C++ reference and when C++ will silently copy an object (copy constructors, etc) the usefulness of references will become apparent. Then when you realize that references have some use limitations you're left with pointers. :)

Hope that gets you started!

Answer (score 0):

Consider following example:

```
 a = {a:1, b:2};
 b = a;
 b.a = 4;
 console.log(a.a); // outputs 4
```

With objects JavaScript acts something like pointers do.

Answer (score 0):

I like to conceptually think of pointers like a giant table with two columns and infinite amount of rows.  In the first column we have addresses to memory and in the second we have values stored at that address it might look something like:

`char *catString = "cat"; //C picked free space at address 3 to hold this string`

```
 Address     Value
    0         23
    1         'r'
    2         12.2
    3         'c'
    4         'a'
    5         't'
    6         '/0'
   ...        ...
```

Where catString actually holds the value 3, not "cat". The string "cat" is in memory whereas the pointer catString just knows where the string is and *points* to the first letter in the string at that memory address.  This is also why strings need a null plug, notice address 6, so when printing, the program knows when to stop printing characters.  `char *str;` is more C style which reads, *an array of characters*, this is equivalent to `string str;` in C++ which is much more string friendly!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take on it.

Think of a pointer as a slip of paper in your hand which tells you to go look in a specific drawer in your kitchen. You can pass that slip of paper around to anyone living in the house and, if they follow the directions on that slip of paper, they all go open the same drawer.

If person A places something in the drawer, then gives the slip of paper to person B at some later time, person B can still go find whatever it is that person A placed there.

And so on.